# Running Cucumber (WATIR) tests in Jenkins, from multiple Feature directories

Tags: ruby, jenkins, cucumber, watir

I am currently running Cucumber (WATIR) tests in Jenkins, with the standard directories structure running a set of features.

The directory structure is as follows -

```
Features
- Pages
-- main.rb
-- httparty_config.rb
-- page1.rb
-- page2.rb
- Step Definitions
-- page1_steps.rb
-- page2_steps.rb
feature_one.feature
feature_two.feature
```

I am now implementing multiple sites, and am wanting to share the same main class (and other configs for HTTParty etc, but separate each of the sites, into their own cucumber sub-directory (for cleanliness purposes).. The following tests run in Rubymine with no issues.

```
Env
- main.rb
- httparty_config.rb
Site_1
    - Features
    -- Pages
    --- s1_page1.rb
    --- s1_page2.rb
    -- Step Definitions
    --- s1_page1_steps.rb
    --- s1_page2_steps.rb
    - s1_feature_one.feature
    - s1_feature_two.feature
Site_2
    - Features
    -- Pages
    --- s2_page1.rb
    --- s2_page2.rb
    -- Step Definitions
    --- s2_page1_steps.rb
    --- s2_page2_steps.rb
    - s2_feature_one.feature
    - s2_feature_two.feature
```

When attempting to run a feature test in Jenkins using this structure, Jenkins fails, as it does not meet the required Cucumber structures.. It cannot find the Feature folder.

How can I keep the new multi-site structure and define the structure so that Jenkins knows where to find each feature, in the different directories?

Answer (score 0):

OK.. So I was making that way more complicated than it needed to be.

I just needed to add a CD command in the Jenkins execute shell command

eg

```
#!/bin/bash
source /home/jenkins/.rvm/bin/rvm 
rvm list
mv gemfile Gemfile
bundle install
cd Site_1
xvfb-run cucumber --format json -o cucumber.json
```